# How to speed up this group by with CSV column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, group-by

I have a simple table: `create table breaktypes (parent_id int, child_id int)`.  The data is basically this:

```
parent_id child_id
125       1
125       3
125       19
125       3722
126       32
126       44
126       13
126       14
127       266
```

Basically a list of parent_id values with child_id values that belong to it.  I would like the data to come back in the fashion below...basically a parent_id with a comma separated list of child_id values.

```
parent_id child_id_csv
125       1,3,19,3722
126       32,44,13,14
127       266
```

So I got the following and it works:

```
SELECT  parent_id ,
        (   SELECT    CAST(bt2.child_id AS VARCHAR(5)) + ','
            FROM      dbo.breakTypes bt2
            WHERE     bt2.parent_id = bt1.parent_id
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS child_id_csv 
FROM    breaktypes bt1
GROUP BY bt1.parent_id
```

This seems to work all right, but it is super slow.  This table contains 10 million records and it takes 105 seconds to bring it back.  Versus just calling `select parent_id, child_id from breaktypes` and getting everything in 18 seconds (but at a tremendous bandwidth cost).

How can I speed up my query?

Comment: Do you have an index for parent_id?

Comment: Why don't you perform this concatenation on the client, which has to loop through all the rows anyway?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't need concatenation on the client...I am doing concatenation on the server for the purposes of reducing the bandwidth requirements.

Comment: ...at the cost of much longer execution times. You need to pick one. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am willing give up a bit of execution time, just not that much.

Comment: @crnlx Yes, there is an index for parent_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the select query is running once for every row, rather than once for every parent.  You might try to do the `distinct` in a subquery:

```
SELECT  parent_id ,
        (   SELECT    CAST(bt2.child_id AS VARCHAR(5)) + ','
            FROM      dbo.breakTypes bt2
            WHERE     bt2.parent_id = bt1.parent_id
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS child_id_csv 
FROM  (select distinct parent_id
       from breaktypes
      ) bt1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not make a difference.

Comment: You do have an index on `breaktypes(parent_id)`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, index is in place (non-clustered).